Audio stutter in macOS when switching from SDL app to any other app
I'm using SDL to write a program that plays arcade game-style music (i.e. chip tune music generated by an emulator core) and I have a timing loop in my code that restricts the application to 30fps. CPU usage according to Activity Monitor averages at around 8-10%.
The audio plays fine in its own SDL window (i.e. the program does not run fullscreen) but as soon as I click away from the window on to another application such as a browser, text editor, etc. there is a very noticeable stutter. I would like the music to continue playing when the window is no longer focussed, but without the stutter (which happens every time I switch from the SDL window to another app, not just intermittently).
What might cause this stutter, and is there a way to mitigate it using SDL? Thank you in advance for any advice/suggestions.
